# C# Selenium - Can't Get Elements in New Tab

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a bit of code that clicks on a link from a webpage which opens a new tab and automatically shifts my view to the new tab. When I try to select elements from that new webpage, I get errors saying the elements do no exist even though they do. Most of the times before the test crashes, the tab actually changes back to the original making me to believe that it is actually searching for the elements on the old tab. I try to use `_driver.SwitchTo().Window(_driver.WindowHandles.Last());` in the hopes that it does something but it just closes out of the window entirely and opens a new blank window. How do I get it so I can get elements from the new webpage and no longer reference the old tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this helper function to switch to your tab of choice. The index is determined by the order they have been created. So your your default tabIndex is 0, if you open a new tab/window it will have tabIndex 1 and so forth..

```
    internal void SwitchToTab(int tabIndex) {
        WebDriver.Instance.Wait(2);
        var newTab = WebDriver.Instance.Driver().WindowHandles[tabIndex];
        Instance.Driver().SwitchTo().Window(newTab);
        WebDriver.Instance.Wait(2);
    }
```

The waits are just for letting the new tab load. These waits are not good practice, so you should look for other methods for waiting for whatever element/state you are waiting for.