# Selenium c# Error on switching to frame. Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on the top of the call stack

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, frame

After login, I am switching to this frame where I am getting the following error:

> "Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on the top of the call stack."

Here is the line of code:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("tabMain__ctl0_ult.org.com-Default");
```

The script has been executed several times and was working perfectly fine. But today all of a sudden I am getting this error. I looked into earlier posts but nothing helped. Please suggest any solutions.

Comment: I reinstalled visual studio and I still have the same problem .

Comment: I have racked my brain for any possible solution and searched for same. Please any suggestions is really appreciated.

Comment: Found an work around or I should rather say source of the issue.

Comment: After I removed the try-catch block it started working. But I would need to still use the try catch block for exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Use this helper function to switch to your tab of choice. The index is determined by the order they have been created. So your your default tabIndex is 0, if you open a new tab/window it will have tabIndex 1 and so forth..

```
internal void SwitchToTab(int tabIndex) {
    WebDriver.Instance.Wait(2);
    var newTab = WebDriver.Instance.Driver().WindowHandles[tabIndex];
    Instance.Driver().SwitchTo().Window(newTab);
    WebDriver.Instance.Wait(2);
}
```

The waits are just for letting the new tab load. These waits are not good practice, so you should look for other methods for waiting for whatever element/state you are waiting for.

This is the same answer I already posted in this thread: [C# Selenium - Can't Get Elements in New Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088000/c-sharp-selenium-cant-get-elements-in-new-tab/45096873#45096873)